# Why do we have the google-calendar tag if we can't ask questions about it here?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, off-topic

I'm just wondering why we have the google-calendar (or any other web application) tag here for superuser when questions on this topic are considered off topic?  I recently had my question migrated away to another forum/community because it was viewed as off topic.

I only asked my original question regarding google-calendar here because the tag appeared for me to select.

Comment: “Google Calendar is part of the Google web application/service suite. Questions about usage and problems should generally be asked at webapps.stackexchange.com unless they involve integration with PC-based software.“

Comment: That was the description of the tag.

Comment: As for the reason it exists, somebody with the prevliage created it, but nobody deleted it.

Comment: _"I only asked my original question regarding google-calendar here because the tag appeared for me to select."_ - So, had that tag not existed you wouldn't have posted your off-topic question here? Weren't you already creating it when you discovered the tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some PC based applications such as the built-in calendar, mail and other applications can connect to web-apps in order to show your online calendars in a system native, and therefore more intuitive, view.

Those applications would definitely be on-topic on Super User and to help narrow down where the problem lies it can be beneficial to know where those applications are getting their data from, especially if it is a third-party service or web application.

If you read the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) you will find a similar exclusion for [android](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android) and [ios](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ios) smartphones that states they are off-topic:

> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

The same applies for web applications, they are off-topic unless the problem is explicitly focused around your computer or web browser program. How to actually use the web applications belongs on the relevant Stack Exchange site: [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I stand corrected.  Should I delete this question since I asked in error and didn't read the tag closely?  Thanks for your answer to my apparently dumb question.

Comment: @Classified I wouldn't say you question is dumb, just that you didn't know that the tag is more contextual. Others might have similar questions so it might be helpful to others in the future.